# How to only disable scroll in ScrollView but not content view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Recently I wrote a small SwiftUI library that can rotate an array of Views and select view.

[image: Gif-1]

But found an issue that I can't figure out how to disable scroll in ScrollView while in normal mode.

[image: Gif-2]

I tried to put `.disabled(true)` at the end of the `ScrollView` unfortunately, it not only disable scroll but also all the views in ScrollView.

Here's [source code](https://github.com/raxabizze/RotateViewManager/blob/development/Source/RotateViewManager.swift) of the [project](https://github.com/raxabizze/RotateViewManager).

What modifier should I add to solve this?

--Edited--

I have tried to change the scroll axis but once it becomes [], scrollview will reset its content offset, wondering if there's a way to block scrolling without changing the axis.

--Solved--

At last, I just add a `DragGesture()` to block scroll event and works fine.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### UPDATE

If your deployment target is iOS 16 (macOS 13) or later, you can use [the `scrollDisabled` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/scrolldisabled(_:)) to enable or disable scrolling.

### ORIGINAL

Only pass `.horizontal` as the scroll axis if you want the view to scroll. Otherwise, pass the empty set.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var shouldScroll: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(axes, showsIndicators: false) {
            Text("Your content here")
        }
    }

    private var axes: Axis.Set {
        return shouldScroll ? .horizontal : []
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not mention this, I have tried this before but once axis set to [], scrollview will reset its content offset and cause some problems to my view. Still, thank you a lot.

Comment: hey any progress /solution with that?

Comment: @raxabizze you just need to set the frame's height when using a horizontal axis, or the frame's width when using the vertical axis. I had kind of the same issue and setting the frame's height worked out :)

Comment: this breaks my hstack content

Comment: this doesn't work... it still scrolls even when set to [ ]

Comment: For the next person that stumbles across this post. This works fine in iOS14. In iOS13 you end up with funny offsets.

Comment: In iOS 14 I still see the content offset reset when you set the axes to an empty array. You're saying it doesn't reset?

Answer (score 18):

I keep coming back to this question and have not been satisfied with any of the answers here. What I found has worked is to create a custom wrapper that evaluates whether a ScrollView should be used or not. It was surprisingly easier than I thought.

### Creating a preventable scroll view

Essentially we want a custom view where scrolling can be toggled. Using a binding, anyone that uses our view will have full control over the scrolling function.

Forgive my naming but `PreventableScrollView` was all I could come up with :)

```swift
struct PreventableScrollView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @Binding var canScroll: Bool
    var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        if canScroll {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: content)
        } else {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially all we need to do is decide whether to embed the content in a ScrollView or just return it directly. Pretty straightforward.

I created a demo to showcase how this might work with dynamic content and the ability to toggle anytime. As I add items it also toggles scrolling.

[image]

Here is the code if you are interested.

```swift
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var canScroll: Bool = false
    let allColors: [UIColor] = [.purple, .systemPink, .systemGreen, .systemBlue, .black, .cyan, .magenta, .orange, .systemYellow, .systemIndigo, .systemRed]
    @State var colors: [UIColor] = [.white]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                PreventableScrollView(canScroll: $canScroll) {
                    ForEach(colors.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        Rectangle().fill().foregroundColor(Color(colors[index]))
                            .frame(height: 44)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
                }.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Toggle(isOn: $canScroll, label: {
                        Text("Toggle Scroll")
                    }).toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: .orange))
                }.padding(.top)
            }
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .padding()
            .background(Rectangle().fill().foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill)).cornerRadius(8))
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    addField()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }).padding()
            }
        }
            .padding()
    }
    
    func addField() {
        canScroll.toggle()
        colors.append(allColors.randomElement()!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works well, but still struggled with the layout a little, needed fixedSize flag in there and a .offset on my content in the PreventableScrollView [latter part]

Answer (score 14):

I tried using the accepted answer provided by Rob Mayoff but the content offset being reset is a frustrating drawback to the suggested approach.

Using the [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) library (which I would recommend for anyone looking for UIKit level controls for SwiftUI APIs - whilst we wait for SwiftUI 2 at WWDC 2020) - you can access the underlying `isScollEnabled` boolean flag of the underlying UIScrollView that powers SwiftUI's `ScrollView` and set is accordingly. Changing the `isScollEnabled` has no impact on contentOffset and works exactly like it should.

It can be implemented as simply as this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var shouldScroll: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Your content here").introspectScrollView { scrollView in
                scrollView.isScrollEnabled = shouldScroll
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It really is that simple with the [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) library!

Comment: This is awesome

Answer (score 13):

I think you can use

```
.simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0), including: .all)
```

It disables scroll in ScrollView but other gestures still work like tapGesture inside this scrollview, and ScrollViewReader also works

Comment: It's like a gem if you're considering using ScrollView to fix any unexpected UI problem. Recently, I ran into a kingfisher image view named KFImage didn't follow its parent's transition in a normal way. To solve this issue, I unintentionally tried to embrace the KFImage with a ScrollView then the problem had gone away. Like my case, if you need to turn off the scroll function of ScrollView (sounds weird though..) for any reason, it's a good approach I think.

Comment: Nice approach... But textfields are disabled with this method

Comment: Great suggestion! I thought I would not be able to do this on iOS 15 so this is great. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 10):

#### Xcode 14 / iOS 16

Now we have explicit environment value for this. So a possible solution would be

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @Binding var shouldScroll: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            // ... other code
        }
        .environment(\.isScrollEnabled, shouldScroll)   // << here !!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I've tried all above and even more. None of solutions works for me. I found next one:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    YourContentView
              .introspectScrollView(customize: { scrollView in
                   scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer()) // disable scrollView scroll      
               })
}
```

Answer (score 6):

with iOS 16 and above it is quite simple:

```
ScrollView {
...
}
.scrollDisabled(true)
```

but for iOS versions less it needs a view modifier:

```
struct DisableScrollingModifier: ViewModifier {
    var disabled: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    
        if disabled {
            content
                .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0))
        } else {
            content
        }
        
    }
}

extension View {
    func scrollingDisabled(_ disabled: Bool) -> some View {
        modifier(DisableScrollingModifier(disabled: disabled))
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
ScrollView {
    ...
}
.scrollingDisabled(true)
```

Comment: It is disabling the scroll and also it is disabling tap gesture. I want tap gesture to be enabled

Answer (score 1):

I went through all the answers and nothing really solved the issue I have been having, so I came up with this solution for those that need to support iOS < 16.

```
ScrollView([]) {
    YourContentView()
}
```

Scroll view accepts the first argument as an axis set. If you provide an empty set, that is - just an empty collection, the scroll will be disabled.

This approach comes in handy if you have a view model, in which you can encapsulate this behaviour and change it in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

May be the answer is too late but that it might help somebody, so sharing this. Also I am developing a project with target iOS 14 and above, so have to deal with some old code. Therefore old technique might come handy for someone.

```
ScrollView([], showsIndicators: false) {
    EmptyView()
}
```

Just need to put empty set in place of axes of **scrollView**, thats it.

Answer (score -3):

That's OK. can try

```
ScrollView {
}
.allowsTightening(true)
.disabled(true)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.