# Swift UI - lock and unlock ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui

In swiftUI - how would I lock/unlock a scrollView dynamically. I know how to read a tap gesture to change a variable, but how can I set a property on the scrollView for this?

```
ScrollView {
    //content
}
```

I know that I can set `ScrollView(.vertical)` or `ScrollView(.horizontal)`, but is there a way to temporarily disable all scrolling axis's... something like ScrollView(nil)

Comment: this attempts it, but solution doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933593/how-to-only-disable-scroll-in-scrollview-but-not-content-view

Comment: I didn't go the modifier route but this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/67430545/1652402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a special `ViewModifier` for that; returning content itself or `ScrollView` containing content, based on a `Bool` value.

```
struct ConditionalScrollView: ViewModifier {
    
    let isEnable: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if isEnable {
                ScrollView {
                    content
                }
            } else {
                content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now, in your `View`, instead of having

```
ScrollView {
    //content
}
```

you should have

```
content.modifier(ConditionalScrollView(isEnable: yourFlag))
```

Comment: fwiw - i also found using Introspect worked, but you'd have to import an external lib for it https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

Comment: definitely prefer the view modifier route :)