# SwiftUI ScrollView disable scroll without disabling interactions with subviews

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

Some similar questions were asked but none with a definitive answer for this issue .
While there are few elements in the stack , i want to disable the scroll in scrollView (which is the natural behaviour in android) .

I can prevent scroll with SrcollView{View}.disabled(true)

However, all interactions with subviews are lost : not Tap,no Drag ...
Even simple ideas would be welcome .

Comment: I must be missing part of the equation here -- if you don't want the user to be able to scroll, why put it in a `ScrollView`? Is it because you want to toggle the scrolling on and off?

Comment: yes, in a full contentView space when ther are for example 2 elements in the list , i want the user to be able to interact with those elements but not scroll those elements up and down when there are nothing more to show . If list has for example 20 elements , it make sense to scroll . I would decide when to make it scroll or not (basically when more elements than the screen size )

Comment: you can code in this way that scrollView would not used in some condition, that would be more doable

Comment: Thank you SwiftPunk, i thought about this at the last solution use dynamically ScrollView only if more than 20 elements for example .Would be doable but not too reactive i guess for dynamic lists. It is just that i m suprised i couldn t find a more elegant solution so far anywhere . Thank you once more

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60910593/12299030?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment . I had seen it . It disables scrolling but also any interaction with sub elements , hence i can not really use it

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Not really , i just built a new structure where i passed the value isDisabled as a parameter and then SrcollView{View}.disabled(isDisabled)

Comment: Now SwiftUI gives us way to do this - solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72525824/12299030.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollView {
    //
}
.scrollDisabled(true)
```