# How to make a unlimited width view in SwiftUI that overflow the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm putting a `ForEach` inside an `HStack`. I hope each element in `ForEach` will keep its original width and the parent `HStack` should overflow the screen as needed. However, this results in that the parent `HStack` fits the width of the screen and each element inside `ForEach` get narrowed down into `1/n * screenWidth`.

Sample Code:

```swift
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
  ForEach(data, id: \.id) { element in
    SomeView(data: element)
  }
}
```

I could achieve a similar effect by putting the parent `HStack` in a `ScrollView`. But what if I don't want the scroll behavior? I wonder how `ScrollView` achieve this infinity width?

Comment: If you don't want scroll behavior, what do you want? Just the last visible view to be clipped? Your question is not clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are trying to achieve, doing that results into breaking the ui.

Take an image for example, put it into a VStack and don't make it resizable.  It will overflow the view. Anything you place in that VStack will overflow too  and won't align within the screens boundaries.

So your best bet is to go with a ScrollView and disable the scrolling as discussed here: [How to only disable scroll in ScrollView but not content view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933593/how-to-only-disable-scroll-in-scrollview-but-not-content-view)

Comment: While the link might answer the question you should post there relevant code in the answer section. Link break over time making answers obsolete.